# What is the lattice of the field $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[p^5-1]{p^2})$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, lattices

Let $p$ be odd prime and $\mathbb Q_p$ be the $p$-adic field. Consider the field extension $K=\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[(p^5-1)]{p^2})$ of $\mathbb Q_p$ of degree $\frac{p^5-1}{2}$.

My question:

> I want see to check whether the line-segment $l:~y=-\frac{p^2(p^3+1)}{p^5(p^5-1)}(x-p^5)$, joining its end points $(0,\frac{p^2(p^3+1)}{p^5-1})$ and $(p^5,0)$, do not contain lattice points of the field $K$.
> How to check it ?

I think we have to find the lattice corresponding to the ring of integers $O_K$ of $K$ ?

If it was rational number field, then the lattice would be free $\mathbb Z$-module of rank $\frac{p^5-1}{2}$ i.e., embedded in $\frac{p^5-1}{2}$-dimensional Euclidean space.

In our case, the lattice of $K$ will be free $\mathbb Z_p$-module of rank $\frac{p^5-1}{2}.$

How to check whether the line-segment $l$ intersect the lattice of $K$ or not ?